# How do I iterate through rows of specific columns of pandas dataframe to perform calucation

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has Stock balance and demand of various product from various depots

Below is the 3 days data of one SKU from one Depot

```
ActivityDate    DepotName   Company SKU  Balance    Demand
1/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1    10         1
2/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     9         1
3/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     8         1
4/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     7         1
```

I want to calculate the safety stock of each day and the formula is

**SafetyStock of 1st Oct = Demand(1stOct+2ndOct+3rdOct) / Balance(1st Oct)**

My first question is

How do I calculate the safety stock for every day?

The answer I am looking for is

```
   ActivityDate   DepotName   Company   SKU  Balance    Demand     SS
    1/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1    10         1      0.30
    2/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     9         1      0.33
    3/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     8         1
    4/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     7         1
```

The larger dataset has all the demand and stock balance for various SKU's and for various depot and it would look like

```
Date       DepotName    Company SKU   Stock Sales
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    10  1
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    20  1
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    30  1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    9   1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    19  1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    29  1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    8   1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    18  1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    28  1
```

In this case how would I calculate safety stock of each SKUs for everyday. Will highly appreciate your help

P.S : For the purpose of understanding , I haven't included the data of other depots and other companies.

I hope I can use this answer to implement on Company and depot level.

Edit 1 :

Just to show you a glimpse of my actual data , it looks like

```
Date       DepotName    Company SKU   Stock Sales
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    10  4
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    20  5
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    30  6
1/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU4    10  4
1/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU5    20  5
1/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU6    30  6
1/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU7    10  4
1/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU8    20  5
1/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU9    30  6
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    9   1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    19  1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    29  1
2/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU4    10  4
2/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU5    20  5
2/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU6    30  6
2/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU7    10  4
2/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU8    20  5
2/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU9    30  6
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    8   1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    18  1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    28  1
3/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU4    10  4
3/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU5    20  5
3/10/2017   Depot2         B    SKU6    30  6
3/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU7    10  4
3/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU8    20  5
3/10/2017   Depot3         C    SKU9    30  6
```

Depots, Company and SKU's have many categories

Basically , I need a code to filter each Depot , each company each SKU and then do the safety stock and so on until all depots, companies and SKUs are covered

Answer (score 2):

Answering your first question, you can use [`pd.Series.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html).

Starting from

```
z = io.StringIO("""\
ActivityDate    DepotName   Company SKU  Balance    Demand
1/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1    10         1
2/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     9         1
3/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     8         1
4/10/2017       Depot1         A    SKU1     7         1""")

df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can do

```
df.Demand[::-1].rolling(3).sum()[::-1]/df.Balance
```

which yields

```
0    0.300000
1    0.333333
2         NaN
3         NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

For your full `df`, you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) before applying a `rolling` sum.

So, starting from

```
z2 = io.StringIO("""\
Date       DepotName    Company SKU   Stock Sales
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    10  1
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    20  1
1/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    30  1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    9   1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    19  1
2/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    29  1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU1    8   1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU2    18  1
3/10/2017   Depot1         A    SKU3    28  1""")

df = pd.read_table(z2, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can first get your rolling sum for your Sales, i.e.

```
df.groupby("SKU").Sales.rolling(3).sum()
```

and the first value on the series of your Stock (i.e. your denominator)

```
df.groupby("SKU").Stock.apply(list).apply(lambda k: k[0])
```

Then, simply divide these values to obtain

```
(df.groupby("SKU").Sales.rolling(3).sum()/df.groupby("SKU").Stock.apply(list).apply(lambda k: k[0]))[::-1]

SKU    
SKU3  8    0.10
      5     NaN
      2     NaN
SKU2  7    0.15
      4     NaN
      1     NaN
SKU1  6    0.30
      3     NaN
      0     NaN
```

Comment: Hi @RafaelC , I get the answer for your first question . However for the 2nd question . My larger dataset has 635303 rows × 6 columns and columns like Depot,Product and SKU all have different levels. Your solution for the 2nd question doesnt work. Can you help ?

Comment: I have to groupby SKU , comapny , depot and activity Date

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an workaround for this question.

First, I have sorted the records by Date

```
df.sort_values('Date',inplace=True)
```

Then I used the combination of groubyby and rolling.

Grouping by on the categorical attributes and rolling on dates with summing Sales.

I have reversed the entire thing to do the forward rolling sum.

```
df1 = (df.iloc[::-1]
        .groupby(['DepotName','Company','SKU'],sort=False)
        .rolling(7, on='Date',min_periods=0).Sales
        .sum()
        .iloc[::-1])
```

Then I merge both the dataframe

```
df = df.merge(df1, on=['Date','DepotName','Company','SKU'], how='left')
```

Then after that I did the safety stock calculation.

```
ss3['SafetyStock']=ss3['7DaysSum']/ss3['Stock']
```